# how to uncache read_chunk in rstudio rmarkdown knitr

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I've been following the instructions under `Executing External Chunks` [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html#executing_code)

I have a `test.Rmd` file:

````
```{r setup}
knitr::read_chunk("example.R")
```
```{r chunk}
```
````

and an `example.R` file:

```
## ---- chunk
print("hello")
```

This works fine when I click the `Run current chunk` button on `{r setup}`, then on `{r chunk}` and produces:

> `[1] "hello"`

However, if I change the code inside `example.R` to:

```
## ---- chunk
print("goodbye")
```

and reload it using the `Run current chunk` button on `{r setup}`, then on `{r chunk}` it produces the original:

> `[1] "hello"`

It looks like it's caching `example.R`. The [documentation](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/) says "Note this function should only be used in an uncached chunk", but changing `{r setup}` to `{r setup, cache=FALSE}` makes no difference.

Comment: I can not reproduce your bug. Works fine fo me. Are you sure you saved `example.R`?

Comment: Yes, I'll try on another machine and get back to you

Comment: it's working on RStudio Version 1.0.153, but not on Version 1.1.383. I need to restart the session and try it out again, but midway through a project,, so might take a few day